# IOS simulator - certificate .pem from cert bot not working - @apollo/client 61: Connection refused

Tags: react-native, ssl, ios-simulator, pem, certbot

When I try drag&drop my cert.pem generated with certbot then I get this error: **One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.**

Simulator IOS 15.2.

Anyone already this problem?

I converted certificate from **.pem** to **.der** but this certificate is not displayed in simulator settings :/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated certbot certificate on the server API and now connection works without certificate on the simulator and device